# The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Student', database 'studentDB', schema 'dbo'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on MVC 4, i am new to it. I was facing a problem when i execute the program, It was showing the error that unable to start IIS server then i changed the server setting using project property.

Also tried terminating the "WebDev.WebServer40.EXE" process, but i need to do that again and again.

I switched to the option "Use local IIS web server" to the "Use visual studio development server" but again it was showing the below error:

```
Unable to connect to ASP.Net Development Server.
```

Now i have hosted the project to IIS server and running my project from that, but now i am facing some error related to database issue, That is:

```
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Student', database 'studentDB', schema 'dbo'
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and connection string in web.config is:

```
<add name="studentDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EFModel.csdl|res://*/EFModel.ssdl|res://*/EFModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SYS6\SQLSERVERR2;initial catalog=studentDB;User Id=username;
Password=password;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Now what's the solution of this problem, I have searched all over on the net but nothing is working?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you have tried, it will be a stab in the dark.

Looks to me like you need to update the privileges for the username that you have specified in the connection string to be able to select from the selected table.

this should help http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx

otherwise, you grant the username the role db_datareader which should let it read data.  it does open up the user quite wide, so i would be careful how you use it.